# How to select specific column from imported table?

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am using the following formula in Google Sheets to pull in some financial data:

```
=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT,"table",4))
```

The `IMPORTHTML` result is

```
Forward Annual Dividend Rate 4    2.04
Forward Annual Dividend Yield 4   1.11%
Trailing Annual Dividend Rate 3   1.94
Trailing Annual Dividend Yield 3  1.05%
5 Year Average Dividend Yield 4   2.02
Payout Ratio 4                    32.93%
Dividend Date 3                   Mar 11, 2020
Ex-Dividend Date 4                Feb 18, 2020
Last Split Factor 2               2:1
Last Split Date 3                 Feb 17, 2003
```

I am `TRANSPOSING` the result to prepare the data for querying:

```
Forward Annual Dividend Rate 4  Forward Annual Dividend Yield 4 Trailing Annual Dividend Rate 3 ...
2.04                            1.11%                           1.94                            ...
```

What I need is the value of the `Ex-Dividend Date 4` column (so: `Feb 18, 2020`) (and later also other columns so I am seeking a generic solution). I have tried multiple ways (see below, but all resulting in `#VALUE!` errors:

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT","table",4)), "SELECT * LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1 WHERE COL=""Ex-Dividend Date 4"")")

=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT","table",4)), "SELECT [Ex-Dividend Date 4] LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1")
```

How do I query this table correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT", 
 "table", 4), 8, 2)
```

or already formatted:

```
=TEXT(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT", 
 "table", 4), 8, 2), "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

in `QUERY`:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT", 
 "table", 4), "select Col2 where Col1 contains 'Ex-Dividend Date 4'", 0)
```